# Make right wall of a maze in c++

Tags: c++, maze

I want to make a maze in C++, however I keep running into a problem with the right outer wall. I was wondering if you guys know a way so I can make the outer wall. Ive been trying to work from up to down using \n, but when \n is used the next symbol just goes to the left wall. Thanks in advance!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

/* class Maze {
    public:
        void makeMaze();
        void Print() const;
    private:
        std::vector <std::vector <char>> Maze;
}; */

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int WIDTH = 4;
    const int HEIGHT = 4;
    /* std::string seedValue = " ";
    HEIGHT = atoi(argv[1]);
    WIDTH = atoi(argv[2]);
    if (argc > 3) {
        seedValue = argv[3];
    }  */
    // row, column
    std::vector <std::vector <std::string>> Maze (WIDTH + 1, std::vector<std::string> (HEIGHT + 1));
    // Roof
    for (int column = 0; column < WIDTH; column++) {   
        Maze[0][column] = "+---";
    }
    // Left Wall
    for (int row = 1; row < HEIGHT + 1; row++) {
        Maze[row][0] = "|\n+";
    }
    // Floor
    for (int i = 1; i < WIDTH + 1; i++) {
        Maze[HEIGHT][i] = "---+";
    }
    // Right Wall

    // FIXME
    
    // Print Maze
    for (int i = 0; i < Maze.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Maze.at(0).size(); j++) {
            std::cout << Maze[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is to much stuff inside `main`. Split this code into smaller functions which are doing single stuff: print maze, read maze, generate maze, solve maze, .... .

Comment: Yh I know but I am first trying to get the maze generation right, then I want to make it tidy;

Comment: Okay, now knowing what your result should look like... There's more issues about your design than I initially thought. To begin with; what dimensions would you say the maze in the image have? I think the last thing you should worry about is the outer walls. The reason for me asking, is that currently, you are storing the outer walls inside of the `Maze` matrix, which will result in lack of space if you don't take that into consideration. Another thing is of course, the outer walls is something you can slap on afterwards.

Comment: So I should first start with making the algortihm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to treat your printable maze as a matrix of chars instead of strings:

- You can consider each cell of the maze border having a horizontal fill `+---` and a vertical fill `+|`, and a `cell_width` and `cell_height`.
- Your maze would be then defined as a matrix of chars sized `maze_height * cell_height + 1` and `maze_width * cell_width + 1`. That extra one is needed for the right and bottom borders.
- In order to fill the border, you can define two helper functions, `fill_horizontal_border_cell` and `fill_vertical_border_cell`. These functions just copy the contents of the strings `horizontal_border_fill` and `vertical_border_fill` respectively to the maze matrix.
- Finally, you'd need to separately fill the bottom left border corner.
- All this code should be properly encapsulated into classes (e.g. `MazeView` for the printable maze, `MazeBorderView` for the printable maze border, and so on).

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/hr54YajPP)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Border
    const std::string horizontal_border_fill{"+---"};
    const std::string vertical_border_fill{"+|"};
    auto cell_width{horizontal_border_fill.size()};
    auto cell_height{vertical_border_fill.size()};

    // Maze
    const size_t maze_width = 6;
    const size_t maze_height = 5;
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> maze(maze_height * cell_height + 1,
        std::vector<char>(maze_width * cell_width + 1, ' '));  // + 1 for the right and bottom borders

    // Fill border
    auto fill_horizontal_border_cell = [&maze, &horizontal_border_fill, &cell_width, &cell_height](size_t row, size_t col) {
        row *= cell_height;
        col *= cell_width;
        for (auto& c : horizontal_border_fill) { maze[row][col++] = c; }
    };
    auto fill_border_vertical_cell = [&maze, &vertical_border_fill, &cell_width, &cell_height](size_t row, size_t col) {
        row *= cell_height;
        col *= cell_width;
        for (auto& c : vertical_border_fill) { maze[row++][col] = c; }
    };
    for (size_t col{0}; col < maze_width; ++col) {  // horizontal borders
        fill_horizontal_border_cell(0, col);  // top
        fill_horizontal_border_cell(maze_height, col);  // bottom
    }
    for (size_t row{0}; row < maze_height; ++row) {  // vertical borders
        fill_border_vertical_cell(row, 0);  // top
        fill_border_vertical_cell(row, maze_width);  // bottom
    }
    maze[maze_height * cell_height][maze_width * cell_width] = horizontal_border_fill[0];  // bottom left border corner
    
    // Print maze
    for (size_t row{0}; row < maze.size(); ++row) {
        for (size_t col{0}; col < maze[0].size(); ++col) {
            std::cout << maze[row][col];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
//   |                       |
//   +                       +
//   |                       |
//   +                       +
//   |                       |
//   +                       +
//   |                       |
//   +                       +
//   |                       |
//   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your current implementation for the most part. The only issue is `\n`. Do not have any of those, they are not needed and will only give you problems. Your `std::cout << std::endl;` makes a new line after each row, that's all you need. So, do not include `\n` in neither the left, nor the right wall

To also "create" the right wall, you can copy what you did for the left wall, but with some minor adjustments:

```
// Right wall
for (int row = 1; row < HEIGHT + 1; row++) {
    Maze[row][WIDTH] = "|";
}
```

Also, what are the pluses for? (`+`)
You don't have to merge the strings together in order to make it work. Your `std::cout << Maze[i][j];` simply adds each string to end of the previous, until you send the `endl` to make a new line.

So, I would say get rid of the pluses, (unless it is for styling).

The left wall should look like this:

```
// Left Wall
for (int row = 1; row < HEIGHT + 1; row++) {
    Maze[row][0] = "|";
}
```

Comment: thats smart, thanks! :D

Comment: So what do you suppose I should change, still kinda banging into a brick wall

Comment: Thank you, but what I run into is the implementation of the + sign, its needed for the assignement (the side wall have to look like this: +
                                                                               |
                                                                              + etc. etc)

Comment: The + and | should be under eachother, but whitespaces are ignored here

Comment: Its in there now ;)